# return a value when a button is clicked in shoes ruby

Tags: ruby, shoes

I have an app using shoes. In the model, I have

```
def run()
    query = get_queries
    executeQuery(query)
    run()
end
```

Then this get_queries will append some buttons to stack, say

```
button "do 1" 
button "do 2" 
button "do 3" 
button "do 4"
```

If the user clicks on the button, get_queries should return the corresponding query (Sometimes it may ask the user for more info, so basically, it returns an array containing query and info). And then the buttons are removed.

However, I am confused as to how to let the buttons return value for that function. I thought of using a variable and check if the variable is updated by busy waiting, but I don't think that is the efficient/right way to do it.

Any suggestions? Or is there another way to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make your program work somewhat differently. Make get_queries append the buttons to the stack, as it does now, but move the other things from the run method into another method that is called only after the button receives a click-event.

```rb
def on_click(button_number)
  executeQuery(button_number)
  run()
end

button "do 1" do
  on_click 1
end

button "do 2" { on_click 2 }
button "do 3" { on_click 3 }
...
```